# Tableau - Show strictly Top N

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following question! I have a barplot which shows top N Sales for each area. There are some times where the sales between an area and another, are equal. When that happens, instead of showing top N, it shows more, since Tableau gets the areas with the same values in the same rank. Any suggestions to show strictly Top N? Thank you in advance!

Comment: In case of tie how do you want Tableau to decide which N? Some criteria had to be specified! Read about four types of rank functions, how tableau camn decide rankings in case of tie.

Comment: I want to pick random Sir. I can't find that you are mentioning.

Comment: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_tablecalculations_definebasic_runningtotal.htm#Rank. Read this.  Meanwhile send me your desired output please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose a data like this

[image]

Regions a and c have equal value of sales.

**Methodology -1**

step-1:  Create a set on 'region field' by taking top N values on your selected measure.  Instead of hardcoding 'N' you can make this set parameter dependent also.  See, in the following screenshot, if top 3 are selected 3 are displayed and not 4

[image]

**Methodology-2**  create a calculated field with the following calculation (table calculation)

```
RANK_UNIQUE(sum([Sales]))
```

when you'll add filter `at most 3` on this field top 3 results will be shown like this

[image]

I think these solve your problem

*Note- If however, `rank_dense` function is used four values will be displayed despite selecting top-3.*  see the screenshot

[image]

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you sir!

Comment: I am glad that it helped.  Call me Anil! No knighthood please :)